# What are the names of the Seven Sisters?

Tags: neil-gaiman, neverwhere

In *[Neverwhere](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?8404)*, Richard encounters Lady Serpentine, one of the "Seven Sisters". We later discover that:

> The Lady Serpentine, who was, but for Olympia, the oldest of the Seven
> Sisters

so we are told the names of two of the seven. Has Gaiman revealed the names of the other five?

Comment: Apparently [a sequel on the Seven Sisters](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34330383-the-seven-sisters) (!) is/was in the works. No word on a release date though.

Comment: If you look at the page for "Seven sisters" on the wiki fandom page for London below they list all the sisters there with references. If someone wants to check their authenticity I think it could be the base of a good answer. https://londonbelow.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Seven_Sisters

Comment: @BjornEriksson - The additional sisters have been added by fans, in response to their inclusion in the [unlicenced RPG game](http://i.4pcdn.org/tg/1379960765169.pdf). They claim that the seven are Olympia, Serpentine, Victoria, **Maida, Stepney, Morden and Caledonia**, but without any obvious justification.

Comment: @Valorum - they should more properly be called Finsbury, Warren, Highbury & Islington… at least they're on the same tube line as Seven Sisters & Victoria ;)) [The names, known & guessed, are London Tube stations, except for Serpentine, which is a lake in Hyde Park.]

Comment: @Tetsujin - I did spend a while trying to work out if there was a common feature among those names. Other than being in London, there doesn't appear to be.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We (currently) know of three of the Seven Sisters; Serpentine, Victoria and Olympia.

> **Neil:** *She* [Lady Serpentine] *is one of seven sisters. You learn about one named in Neverwhere itself, which is Olympia, the eldest.*
>
> **Chris:** *Yes.*
>
> **Neil:** *And Victoria is actually mentioned in the short story at the end of this new illustrated edition – How the Marquis Got His Coat
> Back.*
>
> **Chris:** *I must draw Victoria, I think I might.*
>
> **Neil:** *So that’s three and there are seven of them. I will probably wind up making you draw the other four for me as I write the
> next novel.*
>
> <sub><sup>**[An Exclusive Interview with Neil Gaiman and Chris Riddell](https://www.waterstones.com/blog/waterstones-exclusive-qanda-with-neil-gaiman-and-chris-riddell)**</sup></sub>

We'll almost certainly find out more when Neil (eventually) finishes writing his sequel to Neverwhere, entitled [*The Seven Sisters*](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2017/feb/17/neil-gaiman-announces-neverwhere-sequel-the-seven-sisters).

Comment: Nice find! What is the date on this interview - could things have altered since then?

Comment: It's dated October 2017. I'm on the hunt for anything more up-to-date